# Installing nodejs package - madeye - using npm stalls on ubuntu server?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-10.04

I'm a user, not administrator, on an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Lucid box. When I try to install a node js package using ">npm install -g madeye" - it always hangs on this statement:

make: Entering directory `/nethome/robert/nvm/v0.10.4/lib/node_modules/madeye/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node

I have no idea where to go from here. I successfully installed node v0.10.4 using NVM as a user, and successfully installed other packages - ie. Express.

Comment: I wonder if its because I'm trying to run this from a network share? Which I still don't get, because I'm able to install Express.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the build tools such as `make` and `gcc` installed on your server?

```
[sudo] apt-get install build-essential
```

Also are you sure that you are running in the nvm environment and not the standard node.js? It looks like you are based on the make command output but is something to check

Comment: Did version checks - gcc 4.4.4, and GNU Make 3.81, so its there. I'm running npm install madeye now within ~/nvm/v0.10.4/lib/node_modules, since I see directories for both npm and express in there as the global install location.